# Is there a way to convert HTML code to R tags

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have a HTMl code that needs to be replicated to tags in R. I tried with the below but unable to make it complete, Can anyone help me?

HTML

```
<head>
  <style>
  table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
  </head>
  
  
  <table>
  <tr>
  <th>Month</th>
  <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>January</td>
  <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>February</td>
  <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

R tags

```
  
  tags$head(tags$style("table, th, td{border: 1px solid black;}"), tags$table(tags$tr(tags$th("Month","Savings"))))
```

Comment: Can you pass the html as a string to `shiny::HTML`?

Comment: If you want to do this automatically you can use the **html2R** package.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Like? I tried to google. But did not get

Comment: <https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/html2R/index.html>